# How do I horizontally align a picture with a navigation bar on my site? Also, the borders on my nav bar are messed up? Help a beginner out?

Tags: html, css

Ok, so this is what my site currently looks like. (I can't post an actual pic here apparently) https://i.stack.imgur.com/FxizV.jpg

Is there a way to align that picture with the Home | About Me | Contact nav bar?

Also, as you can see, the borders to the right of Home and About Me are too close to the text. Can I center that between them somehow? I'm slowly building my first site as I teach myself, so i really appreciate your help!

Here's my code:

```css
#firstpic {
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}

#propic {
 width: 15%;
}

#navigation {
 border-bottom: 2px dotted #000000;
}

.bh {
 border-right: 2px solid black;
}

.navbar {
 font-size: 50px;
 text-align: center;
 font-family: Courier;
}

.navbar li {
   display: inline;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title>NAV test</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div id="navigation">
  
  <div id="firstpic"><img src="D:\Testnavbar\Images\Profile Pic.png" id="propic"/></div>
  
  <ul class="navbar">
      <li class="bh">Home</li>
      <li class="bh">About Me</li>
   <li>Contact</li>
  </ul>
  
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you want to align the elements top, bottom or middle?

Comment: like this? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EaEVYP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the image div and the ul to display inline...

See [**this demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/yfwx6em0/)

```
#firstpic {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    display: inline;
}

.navbar {
    font-size: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Courier;
    display: inline;
}
```

Or [**this demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/yfwx6em0/1/) for inline-block

Comment: Sure, add a little padding right to them. See [this update](http://jsfiddle.net/yfwx6em0/2/). And mark the answer accepted, if this worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

Set the divs to be `inline-block` and `vertical-align:middle`

```css
#firstpic {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 15%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background: red;
  height: 50px;
}
#navigation {
  border-bottom: 2px dotted #000000;
}
ul {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
li {
  border-right: 2px solid black;
  padding-right: 1rem;
}
li:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}
.navbar {
  font-size: 20px; /* for demo purposes only */
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Courier;
}
.navbar li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="navigation">

  <div id="firstpic">
    <img src="D:\Testnavbar\Images\Profile Pic.png" id="propic" />
  </div>

  <ul class="navbar">
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>About Me</li>
    <li>Contact</li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Add `padding-right` to push the list text away from the border.

Answer (score 0):

To move the separator over, try adding "padding-right: 20px;" to .navbar li:

```
.navbar li {
    display: inline;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lemoncurry/2xat53n8/

Answer (score 0):

Make the picture one of the list item elements so it displays in-line with the other navigation links. 
Give .navbar a fixed height. 
Set it to vertical-align middle.
Give it a line-height equal to the .navbar height.

```
#firstpic {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        height: 150px;
    }

    #navigation {
        border-bottom: 2px dotted #000000;
        text-align: center;
        height: 100px;
        vertical-align: middle;
        line-height: 100px;
    }

    .bh {
        border-right: 2px solid black;
    }

    ul {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    .navbar {
        font-size: 50px;
        font-family: Courier;
    }

    .navbar li {
        display: inline;
    }


<body>
<div id="navigation">
    <ul class="navbar">
        <li id="firstpic"><img src="D:\Testnavbar\Images\Profile Pic.png" id="propic"/></li>
        <li class="bh">Home</li>
        <li class="bh">About Me</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
    </ul>

</div></body>
```